# How to display available dates?

Tags: website-design, visualization, user-experience

I have an end user who is the admin for a website and they insist on showing the available dates to the customer. They are showing the showings literally like this:

```
2-Mar,  9-Mar,  16-Mar,  23-Mar,  30-Mar-2014

6-Apr,  13-apr,  20-Apr,  27-Apr-2014

4-May,  11-May,  18-May,  25-May-2014

7-sep,  14-Sep,  21-Sep,  28-Sep-2014

5-Oct,  12-Oct,  19-Oct,  26-Oct-2014

2-Nov,  9-Nov,  16-Nov,  23-Nov,  30-Nov-2014

7-Dec,  14-Dec,  21-Dec,  28-Dec-2014
```

My question is, how can i easily and elegantly displays these dates?

Comment: check this display http://sally-brown.net/available-dates/

Comment: Thats a good idea! I could just show 2 columns in a HTML table and it should look much cleaner like that!

Comment: your customer utterly refuses to use a calendar with highlighted "available" dates?

Comment: Does such a thing exist?

Comment: oh, and btw: your question is a little thin on information. It would be useful to know what technology and tools you are using, if you are programming it yourself, if you use a framework, what you have tried.

Comment: yes, of course it exist. But see my comment above. It is difficult to advise without more information

Comment: Concrete5, PHP, jQuery.

Comment: I have tried some jQuery which will create HTML tables and add content into them but its a bit rubbish: http://jsfiddle.net/prBZS/35/

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a wealth of solutions available in the Concrete5 Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hard to come up with very concrete suggestions, as I do not know the exact details of your calendar-needs.

The visually most elegant solution would be something like this:
[image]

But since you are using jQuery (yay!), my first suggestion would be [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):
[image]

There are of course a million alternatives out there, just search for jQuery calendar. 
Another option is of course Google calendar, the web-widget. There are a squillion settings and customisations you can do there.

**Edit:**
Since you gave us info that your calendar might need to be a booking-style one, [check out this list of jQuery calendars.](http://www.twelveskip.com/web-development/web-design/825/12-awesome-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins)

..and I will strongly recommend that you use what is out there, and do not try to build your own from the ground up.

Comment: thanks dude! just need to work out how to display available dates `easily`. Remember the admin has to set the dates for about 30 holidays/trips!

Comment: 30 trips - I did not know that, but you should be able to do it with some clever use of queries.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton: if I were the admin *setting* 30 dates manually, I would want to "import a list" such as the one you posted in your question...